# The zero vector is equal to the sum of the empty space

Tags: linear-algebra

The zero vector is equal to the sum of the empty space.

I see this phrase many times, yet it is never proven. I feel like this prevents me from truly understanding what it is saying or if it is even true.

Can someone please prove this phrase?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of definition. We define the empty sum to be the zero vector since, among other reasons, it then becomes true that the trivial vector space has dimension $0$.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I guess this explains why there aren't any proofs for it - it's simply a definition we've created. Thanks for the answer!